# Made a button class in python but cannot add to screen with pygame

Tags: python, pygame, pygame-surface

```
import pygame, sys, time, random

from pygame.locals import*

pygame.init()

class Button(object):

def __init__(self, x, y):
    '''x_size, y_size,'''
    #self.name = name
    '''self.length = x_size'''
    '''self.height = y_size'''
    self.xpos = x
    self.ypos = y
    self.rect = (100,100)
    self.image = ('Images\Button_Test.png')

def getRect(self):
    return self.rect


def onClick():
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.mouse.get_pressed():
            pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            if self.collidepoint(pos):
                return
```

the main class

```
screen.blit(background,(0,0))
screen.blit(testButton, testButton.getRect())
pygame.display.flip()
```

> TypeError: argument 1 must be pygame.Surface, not Button

Can any one help me solve this error?

Comment: `if event.type == pygame.mouse.get_pressed():` this line is incorrect - you compare two different elements. You can compare `event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN`, and then `if event.button == 1:` and then you can get mouse position `event.pos`.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
screen.blit(testbutton.image,testbutton.get_rect())
```

you're currently telling it to `blit` an object and not the object's sprite